# (iOS 5) when getting list of Twitter accounts, TableView hangs?

Tags: twitter, ios5

I'm trying to get a list of twitter accounts to load up a UITableViewController that contains the data.  I use this function:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
       ...
       [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths ...];
       [[self tableView] reloadData];
       NSLog("This message appears immediately");
       ...
    }];
    NSLog("This message appears immediately");
}
```

For some reason, the interface seems to "hang" for 5 seconds before the table actually gets updated / redrawn (note that I AM calling reloadData!).  All my log messages get printed right away, so I'm not sure what's causing the interface to freeze up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All,

So, I figured it out (sort of).  I guess it has something to do with the threads, I wasn't supposed to do any UI stuff in that thread.

To fix it, I surrounded the table stuff with some dispatching code:

```
[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) 
 { dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     ...
});}];
```

Still need to understand what's going on here, but hopefully this will help if someone runs into the same problem.

Comment: The issue is that UI calls have to happen on the main thread, and `-requestAccessToAccountsWithType:withCompletionHandler:` doesn’t guarantee that its completion block will get called on the main thread. Your use of `dispatch_async` is correct here, though if you have more processing to do before your UI calls then you can freely do it in the background queue before the `dispatch_async` call.

Comment: Thanks mate, had the same issue with another view delaying. This solved it for me.

Comment: Apple's sample code uses performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: to deal with the fact that the handler method is performed on an arbitrary queue.